# Does the while(true) loop end if the operator is a '+' or '-'

Tags: c++

```
double term()
{
    double left = primary();
    Token t = get_token();
    while (true)
    {
        switch (t.kind) 
        {
            case '*':
                left *= primary();
                t = get_token();
                break;
            case '/':
                left /= primary();
                t = get_token();
                break;
            case '%':
                left %= primary();
                t = get_token();
                break;
            default:
                return left;
        }
    }
}
```

This is from Bjarne Strousup programming principles and practice using c++ book, page 201.
I want to ask will the while(true) loop inside term() be terminated  if the operator is '+' or '-'?
if not, under what condition will the while(true) loop be terminated?

Comment: Did you try to run it to see what it does?

Comment: The function will return if the operator is not one of `'%'`, `'/'`, or `'*'`.   That has a consequence of breaking out of the loop.

Comment: Note that you can also run programs one line at a time, when using a debugger. While the program is paused, you can inspect the values of all variables. That way, you should be able to see exactly how the program is behaving, and why it is doing so.

Comment: Nope. i do not have the whole code. i was reading the book halfway and I saw this part. It got me thinking for quite a while.

Comment: The `break` statements belong to the enclosing `switch` and not the `while`. This only ends when the `default` case is hit and the `return` statement is executed.

Comment: A bigger concern is whether or not `get_token()` is well-behaved.  If it begins to fail in some cases and in such cases happens to return the previous token forever, and that happens to be one you handled in your switch, then your loop will spin forever not because of the loop itself but because of the things it depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will terminate the loop.

In the switch there are only cases for `'*', '/', '%'`. Hence, if you pass operator (t.kind) '+' or '-' or precisely any other character it will go to the default case. which return the current value of `left`(according to your program). Since the return statement ends the execution flow of the function, it will also terminate the loop.

Answer (score -1):

The break statement is used in switch to end processing of a particular labeled statement (or case) within the switch statement. It branches to the end of the switch statement.
So you can't break out of the while loop using the break statements inside your switch-case block.

If you really want to break out of while loop from within your switch-case block you can use goto statements.
This is a good read [VS switch-case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/switch-statement-c?view=msvc-170)

Comment: `goto` refactor. `while(condition)` and `condition = false; continue;` can be used. `return` is perfect, considering that functions should not be too large